# How to pass data to getView method

Tags: java, android, listview

> I'm getting a variable data sent from activity to my adapter by using
>   **sendData** method, but every time when I try to access it in my getView method it resets to 0, please help. I've tried to debug code to check if the data from an activity is passing and it looks ok. I also created a getNumb method but still, the variable resets to 0. Here is my adapter code:

```
public class WorkoutListAdapterTwo extends BaseAdapter {

private int y;

public WorkoutListAdapterTwo() {

}

public int sendData(int x){

    this.y = x;
    return y;
}

public int getNumb(){
    return this.y;
}



private static LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = null;

public WorkoutListAdapterTwo(Activity ctx) {
    this.mLayoutInflater = ctx.getLayoutInflater();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return WorkoutContentTwo.WORKOUTSTWO.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return WorkoutContentTwo.WORKOUTSTWO.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    int j = getNumb();
    WorkoutTwo workout = (WorkoutTwo) getItem(j);

    String [] arrOfStrings = workout.name.split(",");

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_workout_row, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.workout_id);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.workout_name);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Set the content for the ListView row
    //holder.id.setText(workout.id);
    //holder.name.setText(arrOfStrings[i]);
    holder.id.setText(Integer.toString(position+1));
    holder.name.setText(workout.ArrList[position]);


    // Set the color for the ListView row
    holder.id.setBackgroundColor(workout.dark);
    holder.name.setBackgroundColor(workout.light);

    return convertView;
}
```

Here I'm adding the code where I'm calling my method:

```
 public void onItemSelected(int position) {
    // Start the detail activity for the selected workout ID.
    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, WorkoutDetailActivityTwo.class);
    detailIntent.putExtra(WorkoutDetailFragmentTwo.ARG_WORKOUT_POS, position);
    WorkoutListAdapterTwo newAdd = new WorkoutListAdapterTwo();
    newAdd.sendData(position);
    newAdd.notifyDataSetChanged();
    startActivity(detailIntent);
}
```

Comment: Can you post code that call `sendData()`

Comment: Do not hold a static layout inflater.  It will leak a ton of memory, as it has a reference to its activity.

Comment: I've added the code below my question

Answer (score 0):

Are you notifying your adapter to update views after updating the value? If your `sendData()` is not called until after the adapter has done it's first draw, you will need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` so that the adapter knows there are new values that should be used to update your views.

Comment: The data is actually passed to the fragment but as soon as I'm calling it in my getView method it resets to 0, I've also tried to use notifyDataSetChanged() but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a interface or you can a use notifyDataSetChanged depends on the use if you are doing search operation then use the notifyDataSetChanged method but if you want to send some data then

Fragment or activity

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment implements MyAdapter.SuccessResponse{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View contentView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), 0);
    myAdapter.successResponse = this;
    return contentView;
}

@Override
public void onSuccess() {

}
}
```

The adapter code

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
SuccessResponse successResponse;

public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

public interface SuccessResponse{
    void onSuccess();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //ur views
    linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view){
            if(successResponse!=null)
                successResponse.onSuccess();
        }
    })
}
```

}

You can use any type of adapter i am use arrayadaper here.